# is it possible to use two different structures in the same code?

Tags: c

I need to add another structure to my code and I wish to know if this is possible?
Below is a snippet of what I want to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "math.h"
#define MAX_CARS 10

struct car {
  double vel, position, desired_vel;
  int index, on_network;
};
typedef struct car Car;

struct car_2 {
  double vel_2, position_2, desired_Vel_2;
  int index, on_network;
};

typedef struct car_2 Car_2;
```

Comment: You can use as many different structures as you want. The question is how much sense that makes, for instance in your example, they're both the same structure with different names, so that seems fairly pointless.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple structures.

Comment: Having a second structure that has the exact same fields than the first one seems completely pointless. What are you _actually_  trying to achieve? Maybe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I think you rather want two variables of the same structure type: `Car car1; Car car2;`

Comment: Hi, as others wrote, yes, you can, but its a completely pointless in the case if they are identical, you can image it as the template, so you will just create instance- "object" with different name, from the same template, its the point which you should go :)

Comment: If your question is about whether you can pass a `Car_2` to a function that expects a `Car` or vice versa, the official answer is "No; they're different types".  The compiler will enforce that if you let it — if you code in modern (post-1990) C.

Answer (score 5):

You can have unlimited struct types in your code. In this instance though, as they both are identical, you can re-use your Car struct and make separate instances with it.

```
Car car1;
Car car2;
car1.vel = 5.0;
car2.vel = 10.0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're answering to the question, although you might have answered to the X question which is behind the the Y one, as suspected @Jabberwocky.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use as many as you want. Example code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct car_dim
{
    int feet;
    float inch;
} card;

struct showroom_loc
{
    int lid;
    int pin;
} carl;

int main()
{
    printf("enter the information for card struct\n");

    printf("Enter feet: \n");
    scanf("%d", &card.feet);

    printf("Enter inch: \n");
    scanf("%f", &card.inch);

    printf("enter the information for car location struct\n");

    printf("enter lid e\n");    
    scanf("%d", &carl.lid);

    printf("Enter pin: \n");
    scanf("%f", &carl.pin);

    printf("struct card= %d\'-%.1f\"", card.feet, card.inch);        
    printf("\nstruct carl= %d\'-%.1f\"", carl.lid, carl.pin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **as many** structures in your code **as you like** as long as their name is different.

However in your example, the members of your structures are identical, maybe you want to do something like this?

```
#define MAX_CARS 10

struct car {
    double vel, position, desired_vel;
    int index, on_network;
};
typedef struct car Car;

int main() {

    // You can define as many instances of type "Car" as you want
    Car car1;
    Car car2;
    Car car3;

    // Or you can use arrays
    Car cars[MAX_CARS];

    cars[0].desired_vel = 100.0;
    cars[1].desired_vel = 120.0;
    // and so on

    return 0;
}
```